# How to fill an array "column" with calculated numbers

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to fill a column of variable length with a series of calculated nontrivial numbers so it can match a set of data in a dataframe column. The result would be a dataframe two columns wide by some large number long (here 20 rows long). I know how to calculate the series:

```
while p < 20:
    r = p * 9890
    d.append(r)
    p +=1
```

but it results in a "horizontal" string:

```
print(d)
```

[0, 9890, 19780, 29670, 39560, 49450, 59340, 69230, 79120, 89010, 98900, 108790, 118680, 128570, 138460, 148350, 158240, 168130, 178020, 187910]

how do I make this a "vertical" column?

Answer (score 0):

Well you're initially building a vanilla python list, which of course does not have a concept of rows or columns, since it is inherently 1D. While I'm not familiar with pandas, assuming it uses numpy arrays, you could do the following:

```
d = numpy.array(d)       #convert to a numpy array
d = d[numpy.newaxis]     #convert from 1D to 2D
d = d.T                  #transpose to make a "column"
```

Or in a single line:

```
d = numpy.array(d)[numpy.newaxis].T
```

Answer (score 0):

using python and pandas

df['new'] = df['datatoiterateover'].apply(function x: x) will put all the data in a new column.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = []
>>> for i in range(20):
...     d.append(i * 9890)
... 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column_header': d})
>>> df.head()
   column_header
0              0
1           9890
2          19780
3          29670
4          39560
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` can create the array very cleanly and can be directly assigned to a `pandas.DataFrame` column or compared with a column in an existing `DataFrame`.  It

```
import numpy as np
...
d = np.arange(20)*980
```

you can compare `d` directly to your `DataFrame` column you don't have to be concerned with its "orientation" vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy.arrays` and slicing:

```
a = np.array([0, 9890, 19780, 29670, 39560, 49450, 59340, 69230, 79120, 89010, 98900, 108790, 118680, 128570, 138460, 148350, 158240, 168130, 178020, 187910])

In [3]: a[:,None]
Out[3]:
array([[     0],
       [  9890],
       [ 19780],
       [ 29670],
       [ 39560],
       [ 49450],
       [ 59340],
       [ 69230],
       [ 79120],
       [ 89010],
       [ 98900],
       [108790],
       [118680],
       [128570],
       [138460],
       [148350],
       [158240],
       [168130],
       [178020],
       [187910]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import *
d=[]
p=0
while p < 20:
    r = p * 9890
    d.append(r)
    p +=1

result=array(d).reshape(20,1)
```